# Cannot upgrade mac mini

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I have a Mac Mini, running OS X 10.7.5, and I try to upgrade it, but I cannot for some reason (in short - I want to install the new XCode and code in Swift).

When I click the "Free upgrade" button nothing happens (pic below). I have triple checked Little Snitch that nothing is blocking the App store or something similar, but found nothing.

Any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: What's the version of your Mac Mini? Did you ensure that Yosemite can be installed in your Mac Mini?

Answer (score 1):

Look up your model here.

http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/index-macmini.html

Then, scroll down to the section marked "Maximum MacOS:", it's towards the bottom on the right.

One of my Mac Minis is the early 2009 Core2Duo model, which is the oldest Mini which supports Yosemite.  If you have a model which is older than 2009, it will only support Lion (Core2Duo), Snow Leopard (CoreDuo/CoreSolo), or Leopard (PowerPC).

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for 'Yosemite' in the Mac App Store, and install it directly from there. This is the same procedure as upgrading.

Comment: This will still perform a hardware check and fail to download if it's an older model.

Comment: And? Then it's not officially supported by Apple and no wonder nothing happens after clicking "Free Upgrade"... And my answer got downvotet why exactly?

Comment: Maybe because it's not accurate.  If you can't upgrade it via the screenshot OP posted above, then searching for it and trying to download it will also fail.

The detail you may have missed is that his Mini is likely too old to support Yosemite.  

I didn't downvote your answer.

Comment: @PatrickMcMahon that may be correct in this case, but I experienced the AppStore not working properly too often, so that the "Free Upgrade" button is not working could be just a bug in the Store... As is not telling anything about why it is failing but failing silently.

Comment: Perhaps, although just about every Yosemite install failure I've seen has to do with the persons Mac being too old and they were unaware of the hardware requirements.  If Yosemite is even being shown as a possible download, it usually indicates the MAS is not the problem.

Lion is the cutoff for many.  Macs which supported 10.8 also supported 10.9, which also support 10.10.

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way to find out if you have a real 2009 model. How many USB ports do you have on the back of your Mac mini. If you have 5 USB ports, you have the 2009 Mac mini and I've put Yosemite on 8 of them so far this year. Go on your 2009 Mac mini and click the black apple (top left of the screen), About this Mac, get more info, look for video or graphics. If you have 256MB video you're fine. 2008 and prior Mac minis only have 64MB of video, that's why, even with a core 2 duo CPU, they can't go past Lion.

Source: We take 2006 core solos and upgrade them to Core2Duo machines that can now take 4GB of ram and thus put Lion on them, which at least does have iCloud support.